# Binary Classification of the sequence at each instance using RNN in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have data instances as-

```
X = [[t1,f11,f21],[t2,f12,f22],[t3,f13,f23]] # t1-time and f11,f21- features
Y = [0,1,?] #we need to predict '?' here
```

Let’s say for training the model, we know 
at t1 (for features f11,f21), the class is 0 and 
similarly in the next time step, at t2 (for features f12,f22), the class is 1, 
so finally we need to predict whether for the next time step t3 (for features f13,f23), the class is 1 or 0 or (probability).

How can I input this into RNN using Keras?
Can TimeDistributed Layer be applied in this case?

Comment: This is a sequence-to-sequence problem. I'd advice you to look at encoder-decoder models.

Comment: But I don't want sequence to be predicted. In short, given a sequence of three inputs, if the first two inputs gives output 0 and 1 respectively then what would be the output of the third input in the sequence based on the learning from the first two inputs. So its just the **prediction of output(0/1) of the last instance based on the previous instances' input and output in the sequence**.